# Will viewModel gets updated automatically, when we remove an item from the its view?

Tags: mvvm, kendo-ui

I have a view, I have bind this view to a view Model having list items.

When I make any changes to view Model corresponding changes I could see in view.

But when I remove an item from view it is not getting updated in viewModel.

I am using KendoUi for above.

Can any one please let me know what is the issue here

Comment: Who knows, considering you haven't given us any relevant code snippets.

Answer (score 0):

I assume ViewModel collection is of type ObservableCollection. Use a two-way binding to accomplish what you need.

```
ItemsSource = {Binding Path=MyCollection, Mode=TwoWay}
```